# How can Windows 7 disallow "tapping the mousepad (touchpad) to work as a click"?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, touchpad, mouse-click

I have a Dell Studio 15 notebook which is about a year old, and the old Vista on it has a tool in the control panel to disable "tapping the mousepad (touchpad) to work as a click", because very often, something is accidentally clicked on (online game or links)...

But Win 7 is installed on it on a new partition, and now there seems to be no tool to disallow that?  The Mouse doesn't have any setting to control that.  Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is on

[The Synaptics touchpad driver cannot prevent the touchpad from "tapping = click"](https://superuser.com/questions/80225/the-synaptics-touchpad-driver-cannot-prevent-the-touchpad-from-tapping-click)

Answer (score 4):

download and install the latest **[Synaptics touchpad driver](http://www.synaptics.com/support/drivers)**.

additionally you can install [**TouchFreeze**](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Windows-Widgets/System-Utilities/TouchFreeze.shtml), which will automatically disable the touchpad while you are typing text.

*TouchFreeze is freeware (although it says for Windows NT / 2K / XP / 2003 only, i have it working in Vista, so it should be OK with Windows 7 too).*

Comment: after downloading the driver and restarting the machine, there is still no control to disable the "tap as a click"...  there is now control to use left click to "Start Media Player" and also a bunch of other functions for the right click... but there is no where to disable the tap as a click.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, this can be disabled in the driver for the touchpad. In my dell notebook, this was a synaptics touchpad, and it was possible to configure it so that it is disabled as soon as another pointing device (mouse) is connected to the notebook. You should be able to download the correct driver for your device from the dell support pages.