# The Synaptics touchpad driver cannot prevent the touchpad from "tapping = click" 

Tags: windows-7, mouse, touchpad

This is related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/79530/how-can-windows-7-disallow-tapping-the-mousepad-touchpad-to-work-as-a-click).

the [Synaptics touchpad driver](http://www.synaptics.com/support/drivers) cannot prevent the touchpad from treating a tap as a click.  Is there some window that is not seen that actually can set it or can there be any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried using Synaptics for that same purpose. It never worked. If you go to 
[Dell Support](http://support.dell.com) if you're running a dell, the pointing stick driver will enable you to control "tap to click" preferences.

Comment: it simply works.  go to the dell support website, type in Pointing Stick, and there will be a list of drivers to download.  There is a current one good for "all OS 32 bit or 64 bit".  I chose that one and installed and it worked.